# SQL Server - How to display values that differ in two similar tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 2 tables in SQL Server (ver:2008). Both tables have similar structure. Second table has few extra columns. I want to write a query that displays the differences in these tables (for matching fields). Output should display columns from both tables side by side (for comparison).

I tried using EXCEPT which is displaying the results from table 1 that don't match the results in table2. But I need to display both results side-by-side.

Thank you.

Comment: Just to be clear.... you want de differences between data on X columns or Differences beteen columns definitions, Example X on A is varchar(10) and X on B is varchar(11)?

Comment: Data. Not the column definitions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to select the fields you wish to display:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
  from table1 t1
 inner join table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
 where t1.field1 <> t2.field1 OR t1.field2 <> t2.field2
    OR ...
```

Comment: This approach requires all fields in my where condition. Isn't there a better way to avoid that. For ex: EXCEPT gives all fields that are different, how to use that information to display fields from both tables.

Comment: This does not compare null values, if for example t1.field1 has null value but t2.field has a value (other than null) it will not show in compare result although they are not similar

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you have 2 tables, `Products1` and `Products2`, both with columns `Name`, `Price`, `Color` etc., and you want to list all different products, you can use this:

```
SELECT Name FROM Products1
UNION
SELECT Name FROM Products2
```

OR, you can use FULL JOIN keyword, it returns rows when there is a match in one of the tables. For example:

The “Cars” table:

```
P_Id  Name      Color  Quality  City
----  --------  -----  -------  -----------
1     BMW       Red    good     Las Vegas
2     Lexus     Blue   bad      Los Angeles
3     Mercedes  Green  good     MIami
```

The "Orders" table:

```
O_Id  OrderNo  P_Id
----  -------  ----
1     123      3
2     234      3
3     345      1
4     456      1
5     689      18
```

Now we want to list all the cars and all the people with their orders.

We use:

```
SELECT Cars.Name, Cars.Color, Orders.OrderNo
FROM Cars
FULL JOIN Orders
ON Cars.P_Id=Orders.P_Id
ORDER BY Cars.Name
```

The result:

```
Cars      Color  OrderNo
--------  -----  -------
BMW       Red    345
BMW       Red    456
Mercedes  Green  123
Mercedes  Green  234
Lexus     Blue   -
-         -      689
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.  It assumes that there's one column (a) that is identical between the tables, and the rest (b, c, ...) are potentially different.

```
SELECT t1.a, t2.a, t1.b, t2.b, t1.c, t2.c, ...
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.a = t2.a
  AND NOT (t1.b = t2.b AND t1.c = t2.c ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
) T1

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
) T2
```